# Is it possible to make an alias for !:0 , or is there an alternative?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Being truthful, I find the shortcut `!:0` not being short enough, considering it also requires the shift key.

I was wondering if I can make an alias or function for it, I'm aware I'm missing something. I did the obvious:

```
pr() {
    !:0
}
```

And:

```
alias pr="!:0"
```

Alternatively, does something like `Alt + .` exist, but for the command only section ($0)? I was not able to find anything.

Comment: [`pr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html) is an existing Unix command, you should pick some other name for your alias or function to avoid breakage in your code and/or other tools you use now or in future that might be calling `pr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `!:0` is not the command in the last line of history. It's the first word. So if you run `A=B some-command arg1`, `!:0` will be `A=B`.

That said, since you mention <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>, which is:

> `yank-last-arg (M-. or M-_)`
>
> Insert last argument to the previous command (the last word of
> the previous history entry). With a numeric argument, behave exactly
> like `yank-nth-arg`.[...]

There's the aforementioned [`yank-nth-arg`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-yank_002dnth_002darg-_0028M_002dC_002dy_0029):

> Insert the first argument to the previous command (usually the second
> word on the previous line) at point. With an argument *n*, insert the
> *n*th word from the previous command (the words in the previous command
> begin with word 0).

So you could do  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>, or, since `yank-last-arg` behaves "exactly like `yank-nth-arg`" with an argument, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.

You can make a binding for this, but it's a bit roundabout - [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67536183/2072269) readline doesn't have a mechanism to bind to a command while specifying an argument. You have to [bind to a key sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010170/2072269) which first imitates sequence for an argument and then then the sequence for an existing binding, so you could do:

```
bind '"\e,": "\e0\e."'
```

And press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to get the first word.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using `fc`:

```
alias pr='fc -e "sed -i s/\ .*//"'
```

This asks `fc` to start an editor with the last command entered, wait for the editor to exit, and run (potentially modified) command. Instead of a regular editor, the alias uses `sed` to only keep the first word of the command.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without instantly running? Would like to edit a new argument first